# How to send signal r messages to specific user logged in using azure functions?

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions

Hi I am working in azure functions and azure signal r. I have front end application with azure ad authentication. I want to send signal r notification to specific user through azure function. Below is my react code.

```
constructor(props: IMapUpload) {
        super(props);     
        this.fileUploaderRef = React.createRef<FileUploader>();
        this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:7071/api")
             .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
             .build();//  https://wadevdvlgenseawe02-webapi.azurewebsites.net/MapUpload
         this.hubConnection.start().catch((err: string) => console.log(err)); 
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.hubConnection.on("newMessage", (message: string) => {
            console.log(message);
            //Pass the Map File Url to Site Details
            this.props.onMapFileUpload(message);
            this.handleProgress(message);
         });
         
         const sarId= this.props.sarId;        
         this.props.sar?.getMapFileDetails(sarId, null, null);
    }
```

Below is my azure functions

```
    [FunctionName("Negotiate")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "negotiate")] HttpRequest req, IBinder binder)
        {
            if (req.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                var principal = TryGetPrincipal(req.Headers["Authorization"].ToString());
                if (principal != null)
                {
                    var connectionInfo = await binder.BindAsync<SignalRConnectionInfo>(new SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute
                    {
                        HubName = "MapUpload",
                        UserId = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
                    });
                    return new OkObjectResult(connectionInfo);
                }
            }

            return new UnauthorizedResult();
        }

        public static ClaimsPrincipal TryGetPrincipal(string jwtToken)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();

            validationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;

            validationParameters.ValidAudience = "e51c317b-87e7-4cb3-95f0-37cb52b6f873";
           // validationParameters.ValidIssuer = _issuer.ToLower();
            validationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(".Kmt.LP_f2D3.E8MY.TXyve.-sgr6770j_"));

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);


            return principal;
        }
 [FunctionName("Negotiate")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "negotiate")] HttpRequest req, IBinder binder)
        {
            if (req.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                var principal = TryGetPrincipal(req.Headers["Authorization"].ToString());
                if (principal != null)
                {
                    var connectionInfo = await binder.BindAsync<SignalRConnectionInfo>(new SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute
                    {
                        HubName = "MapUpload",
                        UserId = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
                    });
                    return new OkObjectResult(connectionInfo);
                }
            }

            return new UnauthorizedResult();
        }

        public static ClaimsPrincipal TryGetPrincipal(string jwtToken)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();

            validationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;

            validationParameters.ValidAudience = "myclientid";
           // validationParameters.ValidIssuer = _issuer.ToLower();
            validationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysecrete"));

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);


            return principal;
        }
    
            [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "myconn")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log,
                [SignalR(HubName = "MapUpload")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
                return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                    new SignalRMessage
                    {
                        //UserId = "test@mydomain.com",
                        Target = "newMessage",
                        Arguments = new[] { myQueueItem }
                    });
    
            }
```

If I havelogged in with test@mydomain.com in my front end application then only for test@mydomain.com I want to send message. If I add userid then messages are not getting delivered and If I remove message is getting delivered to everyone. Then I did some research and found I need to add `UserId = "{headers.x-ms-client-principal-id}"` but after adding this I started getting below error

```
http://localhost:7071/api/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Internal Server Error
```

I am struggling to solve this. Can someone help me what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The header that you are using is applicable only if you are using the built-in [Authentication/Authorization feature of Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to?toc=/azure/azure-functions/toc.json). Could you confirm?

Comment: Hi Pramod, In azure function I am not using any kind of authentication/authorization. But my ui application has azure ad authentication. My ui app is in react js SPA and I am using azure ad implicit flow.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using the built-in authentication/authorization feature, the header that you are using is not applicable. Instead, you could extract the `upn`/`email` from the JWT token passed and leverage [runtime binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime) to pass this extracted value as the `UserId`.

With this, you should later be able to send notifications to specific users using the passed `UserId`.

Comment: Hi Pramod, How can I receive JWT token  GetSignalRInfo method?

Comment: You would simply extract the token from the authorization header. In C#, `req.Headers['Authorization']` should return the token value, which you could parse and extract the identity from it (usually the email claim should do)

Comment: Hi Pramod, I changed my code as above to get token. I added Run Binding in negotiate. Now I will get token and user info but how messages will be send to specific user. second tun method will be used to push notification but how that method will come to know to send messages to specific user?

Comment: You would have to pass the exact user ID of the user that you want to notify when [sending a message using the binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=csharp#send-to-a-user).